# How can I use my Google Account with Apple apps (Mail, Calendar, etc) in OS X 10.10 and older?

Tags: mail.app, calendar, gmail, notes.app, google

For months, Google has been warning me that I "may lose access to apps that are using less secure sign-in technology".

[image: email]

The warnings directed to [this page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) with more information. Starting on May 30, Google was planning to prevent software which does not use the modern OAuth2 authentication scheme from logging into any Google account. Unfortunately, this includes Apple applications built into OS X 10.10 and older, such as Mail, Contacts, and Calendar. (This applies even to accounts added via "Sign in with Google", and even though "less secure app access" was not previously required.)

I am using OS X 10.9 Mavericks. As was foretold, on the morning of June 1, 2022 at around 7 am EDT, the Mail, Calendar, and Notes apps spontaneously became unable to connect to my Google account.

How can I use my Google account without updating to an ugly flat version of OS X?

Comment: Some hardware won't support 10.10.  All hardware that supports 10.10 supports 10.11.  How about using apps/mods to restore the old look to the new OS? Crazy to have bad security just because you like aesthetics.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Just to give an idea of how far down the rabbit hole I am, I built a Hackintosh system explicitly targeting 10.9 compatibility (while retaining as much performance as possible), made a QuickTime plugin to add support for modern codecs, and am currently working on a kext to monkey patch a bug Apple left in the XNU kernel prior to Sierra. I tried using mods for years, but it's basically impossible to do comprehensively, and aesthetics—while a major factor—aren't the only reason I prefer 10.9.

Comment: I'm not surprised, support for prior to 10.11 has been dropped with extreme prejudice.  10.11 is reasonably well loved since it supports *a lot* of hardware, and they "kinda owe" those owners since they were forced to replace their Macs due to the Intel switchover.    Unfortunately 10.11 introduces *a bunch* of baked-in security stuff that <=10.10 does not have, you may have noticed how StackExchange and Wikipedia stopped working on it last year.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine I set up a mitm proxy last year to work around 10.9's https limitations, so Wikipedia et al work just fine. More at: https://jonathanalland.com/old-osx-projects.html. As I said—deep in the rabbit hole!

Comment: Seeing your questions reach HNQ every now and then makes me smile. As someone who also hates flat design I'm still keeping a Mavericks box for occasional spreadsheeting on Office 2011. I never really liked OS X enough so I've moved on to Linux however it's fun seeing somebody keep on the fight. @Harper-ReinstateUkraine tweaks are prohibitively hard, things as simple as changing icons and mouse curves aren't really supported.

Comment: @WesToleman yeah, but OP is neck deep in much worse lol.  I didn't mean "fragile" so much as "high maintenance"... I used to hack PCs like that, but then I decided I no longer wanted to work in IT lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google still offers a workaround for applications that don't use OAuth2, but they don't publicize it. You need to create an "[app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)", and use that to sign in instead of your normal password.

First, go to https://myaccount.google.com/security and turn on "2-Step Verification". Follow the instructions to add a verification method for your Google Account. Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid this.

Afterwards, go back to https://myaccount.google.com/security and select the newly-available "app passwords" option. Use the options provided to generate a new app password.

Finally, remove your Google Account from System Preferences, then add it back again using your newly-generated app password in place of your normal password. (I recommend completely removing and re-adding the account like this to avoid potential problems with sending messages in Apple Mail.)

Afterwards, you will once again be able to use Mail, Contacts, Notes, Reminders, and Calendar/iCal with your Google Account.

---

If Google ever removes the app password feature (I don't think they will, lest they cut off every plain IMAP email client), consider trying
Yo'av Moshe's [OAuth Hopper](https://github.com/bjesus/oauth-hopper) instead, which should also work.

Comment: As of August 2023, this is no longer working for syncing Contacts and Calendar, but it is working for Email, which is what really matters. I've transferred my personal Contacts and Calendars to use an iCloud account instead. This still works from OS X 10.9.

Comment: In addition, I recently started a new job that uses Google Workspace, and I wanted to sync email and calendars. I created an app-specific password, but for some reason this did not work in System Preferences when I tried to add it as a Google account. However, when I selected "Add Other Account" → "Add a Mail account", I was able to add my email with the same credentials.

Comment: That just left syncing the Workspace Google Calendar. I got it working, but I did have to use OAuth Hopper. It was tricky to set up and I don't understand what I did well enough to precisely document the process. What I will say is (1) you need to set up an OAuth Client ID in console.cloud.google.com, and (2) GPT4 was very helpful in figuring this out. I fed it OAUTH Hopper's readme and then asked for more specific details.