# Error: imap.mail.com is not responding

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, imap

I can't tell if it's just mail.com that's down or my old iOS 9 that doesn't work right.

I usually check my emails on my iPod touch 5 because it's more covenient.

But ever since 2 days ago, my Mail.com email (xxx@email.com) will not work. I have a couple of accounts at mail.com and I've added them to the iMail client a while back.

All the sudden none of the emails work.

Only my icloud/gmail/etc. emails work. Not the ones from mail.com.

When I check for mail in any folders/inboxes, it says "Updated Yesterday"

It was working fine 3 days ago, and I never did anything to my account.

I'm guessing this is more specific to mail.com because everything else works.

Is mail.com down?

Comment: I don't know why this would be happening on mail.com rather than gmail, but is there any chance at all this is related to Google's recent change? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441897/how-can-i-use-my-google-account-with-apple-apps-mail-calendar-etc-in-os-x-10 somehow? The timing, combined with the fact that you're on iOS 9, seems highly suspect. Except it's the wrong email provider...

Comment: Strange. I didn't know there was anything wrong with gmail, but my gmail account is fine. Mail.com's website doesn't say anything happened. The email through the website works fine. Just not the app

Comment: You know, actually on mail.com my recovery email/backup email is my icloud email which is also linked to my gmail account. Otherwise I don't know why this would happen at the exact same time. (Also related to that post my email stopped working at 7:46 AM)

Comment: It doesn't look like https is the culprit either. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.com says that mail.com still supports iOS 9 compatible cipher suites, and the site is using a root certificate that should be trusted by default in IOS 9. Have you tried simply deleting the account and re-adding it?

Comment: I've tried reconfiguring the smpt/imap server. That didn't work though